# I'am consuming geoapify api to get latitude and longitude of particular address . Can anyone cast this into proper classes, Here is my json

Tags: java, json, geoapi

{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{
"type": "Feature",
"properties": {
"datasource": {
"sourcename": "openstreetmap",
"attribution": "© OpenStreetMap contributors",
"license": "Open Database License",
"url": "https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright"
},
"name": "Via Acquaviva",
"country": "Italy",
"country_code": "it",
}
}
]
}